# Update excel file with first row of html table (pandas/python)

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas

I want to update my data which I exported from html table to excel.
Problem is, I want to keep the old data.

I have 3 temperature sensors, each one has a webpage where I get the data and export it into an excel file .
Each sensor has mutliple pages, as there is a lot of data.

I managed to export everything to the .xlsx files, but when I start the script again, the oldest data row gets lost, as the webpage only displays (about) 30 days of data.

**What it does:**
Reading each page from 1 to 25 for each sensor, putting all data from sensor into seperate excel file.

**What it should do:**
Check if the first row in html table matches the first row in excel table, if true do nothing, if false add new row on top in the excel sheet.

And yes, I know the code isn't very well optimized as I'm not working with pyton for very long. Any help for variables for the urls are much appreciated (the urls aren't exactly the same tho -> page=n and deviceid=x )

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

print "Starting fenster 3.."


fenster_3_seite_25, = pd.read_html("URL", header=0)
... ##deleted other rows for overview
fenster_3_seite_1, = pd.read_html("URL", header=0)

print "Collecting data for fenster 3 done! Creating file fenster_3.xlsx"

fenster_komplett = pd.concat([fenster_3_seite_1, fenster_3_seite_2, fenster_3_seite_3, fenster_3_seite_4, fenster_3_seite_5, fenster_3_seite_6, fenster_3_seite_7, fenster_3_seite_8, fenster_3_seite_9, fenster_3_seite_10, fenster_3_seite_11, fenster_3_seite_12, fenster_3_seite_13, fenster_3_seite_14, fenster_3_seite_15, fenster_3_seite_16, fenster_3_seite_17, fenster_3_seite_18, fenster_3_seite_19, fenster_3_seite_20, fenster_3_seite_21, fenster_3_seite_22, fenster_3_seite_23, fenster_3_seite_24, fenster_3_seite_25], ignore_index=True)
fenster_komplett.to_excel("fenster_3.xlsx", index=False)

print "Fenster 3 done!"

print "Starting privat.."


privat_seite_25, = pd.read_html("URL", header=0)
... ##deleted other rows for overview
privat_seite_1, = pd.read_html("URL", header=0)

print "Collecting data for privat done! Creating file privat.xlsx"

privat_komplett = pd.concat([privat_seite_1, privat_seite_2, privat_seite_3, privat_seite_4, privat_seite_5, privat_seite_6, privat_seite_7, privat_seite_8, privat_seite_9, privat_seite_10, privat_seite_11, privat_seite_12, privat_seite_13, privat_seite_14, privat_seite_15, privat_seite_16, privat_seite_17, privat_seite_18, privat_seite_19, privat_seite_20, privat_seite_21, privat_seite_22, privat_seite_23, privat_seite_24, privat_seite_25], ignore_index=True)
privat_komplett.to_excel("privat.xlsx", index=False)

print "Privat done!"

print "Starting tuer 3.."


tuer_3_seite_25, = pd.read_html("URL", header=0)
... ##deleted other rows for overview
tuer_3_seite_1, = pd.read_html("URL", header=0)

print "Collecting data for tuer_3 done! Creating file tuer_3.xlsx"

tuer_komplett = pd.concat([tuer_3_seite_1, tuer_3_seite_2, tuer_3_seite_3, tuer_3_seite_4, tuer_3_seite_5, tuer_3_seite_6, tuer_3_seite_7, tuer_3_seite_8, tuer_3_seite_9, tuer_3_seite_10, tuer_3_seite_11, tuer_3_seite_12, tuer_3_seite_13, tuer_3_seite_14, tuer_3_seite_15, tuer_3_seite_16, tuer_3_seite_17, tuer_3_seite_18, tuer_3_seite_19, tuer_3_seite_20, tuer_3_seite_21, tuer_3_seite_22, tuer_3_seite_23, tuer_3_seite_24, tuer_3_seite_25], ignore_index=True)
tuer_komplett.to_excel("tuer_3.xlsx", index=False)

print "Tuer 3 done!"
```

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient way of doing it. But, if you have a date field in the data, you could simply import the old data first with a pd.read_excel() then add it to the pd.concat() function and then do a drop_duplicates() on it. See example below.

```
existing_excel = pd.read_excel(excel_path,sheet_name)
final_excel = pd.concat([existing_excel,new_pd1,new_pd2])
final_excel.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
final_excel.to_excel(excel_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! I tried before but I didn't know there was a drop_duplicate. Now it works. I'll try to clean up my code now, thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind selecting this as the correct answer / upvoting my answer?

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help :)